# How to make two ec2 instances connected with each other internally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two ec2 instances on one region and one of the instance is running a sever on port `8080`. The security setting for these instances is to block all port except 22. How can I let one instance open port `8080` only for the other ec2 instance? I know how to set the inbound port number in security group setting but it will make `8080` to be public. How can I enable the port only for one particular ec2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you have server running on instance, let's say, `i-ssssss`. Client is running on instance `i-cccccc`. And you want instance `i-cccccc` to access port `8080` of `i-ssssss`. Your actions are:

1. Create security group `sg-cccccc`
2. Create security group `sg-ssssss`
3. Create inbound rule for `sg-ssssss` where:

   - `Type` is `Custom TCP Rule`
   - `Port Range` is `8080`
   - `Source` is `sg-cccccc` (yes, you can specify security group as inbound rule source)
4. Attach `sg-cccccc` to instance `i-cccccc`
5. Attach `sg-ssssss` to instance `i-ssssss`

There are other options and nuances. For example you could have only one security group attached to both instances. In this case all instances having this sg attached would be able to open needed port for all other instances in this sg.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tired and it works only for internal IP not public IP. Is there a way to configure `sg-ssssss` to allow request from `sg-cccccc` through its public IP?

Comment: @ZhaoYi as far as I know, no, this solution won't work for public interface. To make it work for public interface you will have to create rule that allows access from client's public ip.